# Change tkinter Label in other class?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Can somebody help me please, I'm making an exercise about class and running task on other thread then tkinter. I want to change the label in another class. Can't get my script to work.

I tried different things but I'm having some troubles with understanding the inheriting from classes and the threads, so this is just an example to learn more about it.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading

#Gloabl for stopping the run task
running = True

#class 1 with window
class App():

     def __init__(self):
          #making the window
          self.root = tk.Tk()
          self.root.geometry("400x400+300+300")
          self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)
          self.widgets()
          self.root.mainloop()

     # stop task and close window
     def callback(self):
          global running
          running = False
          self.root.destroy()

     # all the widgets of the window
     def widgets(self):
          global labelvar
          #startbutton
          self.start_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Start",     command=lambda:App2())
          self.start_button.pack()

          #stopbutton
          self.stop_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Stop", command=lambda:self.stop())
          self.stop_button.pack()

          #Defining variable for text for label
          labelvar = "Press start to start running"
          self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text=labelvar)
          self.label.pack()

     #stop the task
     def stop(self):
          global running
          running = False


#class 2 with task in other thread
class App2(threading.Thread):

     def __init__(self):
          global running
          #check if task can be run
          running = True
          threading.Thread.__init__(self)
          self.start()

     def run(self):
               #starting random work
               for i in range(10000):
                    print(i)
                    labelvar = "running"
                    App.label.pack()
                    #checking if task can still be running else stop task
                    if running == False:
                         break
                         labelvar = "stopped"
                         App.label.pack()

#initiate main app
app = App()
```

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't inherently support multithreading. Only the main thread can make calls to it to update the GUI—so while you _can_ use threads, you'll need to be mindful of that restriction and code around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading itself, but you *can* do it as long as only one thread, usually the main one, uses (or "talks") it.

If you want to affect what the GUI displays, the other thread(s) must communicate somehow with the GUI thread. This is often done through a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#), but in this relatively simple case it can be done through a `global` variable *provided that concurrent access to it is controlled* by some means—sharing memory space (i.e. global variables) is one of the advantages of multithreading vs multitasking, but it has to be done and done correctly.

An easy way to share a resource like this is by using a [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) dedicated for that purpose. (See the Wikipedia article [***Lock (computer science)***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) for more details.)
All references to this shared resource (the `running` flag) should only be done after "acquiring" the `Lock` and "releasing" it afterwards. Fortunately it's trivial to do this using a Python [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement (as shown below).

Another crucial aspect of the multithreading problem is how any information exchanged between the two threads is processed. In this case I choose to make the `tkinter` thread **poll** the running flag, watch for changes, and update any affected widgets accordingly. This can be done by using the universal widget method [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) which tells `tkinter` to schedule a future call (inside the 'mainloop') to a user-supplied function or method and to pass it certain arguments. To get this to happen repeatedly, the called function can reschedule *itself* to run again by calling `after()` before it finishes.

Below is a modified version of your code that does these thing. Note that `App2` never calls `tkinter` or touches any of its widgets, which is why it works.

```
import threading
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

DELAY = 100  # millisecs between status label updates

# global flag and a Lock to control concurrent access to it
run_flag_lock = threading.Lock()
running = False


# class 1 with window
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        global running
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("400x400+300+300")
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)
        self.create_widgets()
        with run_flag_lock:
            running = False
        self.root.after(DELAY, self.update_status, None)  # start status widget updating
        self.root.mainloop()

    # create all window widgets
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.start_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Start", command=self.start)
        self.start_button.pack()

        self.stop_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Stop", command=self.stop)
        self.stop_button.pack()

        self.status_label = tk.Label(self.root, text='')
        self.status_label.pack()

    def update_status(self, run_state):
        """ Update status label text and state of buttons to match running flag. """
        # no need to declare run_flag_lock global since it's not being assigned a value
        with run_flag_lock:
            if running != run_state:  # status change?
                if running:
                    status_text = 'Press Stop button to stop task'
                    run_state = True
                else:
                    status_text = 'Press Start button to start task'
                    run_state = False
                self.status_label.config(text=status_text)
                # also update status of buttons
                if run_state:
                    self.start_button.config(state=DISABLED)
                    self.stop_button.config(state=ACTIVE)
                else:
                    self.start_button.config(state=ACTIVE)
                    self.stop_button.config(state=DISABLED)

        # run again after a delay to repeat status check
        self.root.after(DELAY, self.update_status, run_state)

    # start the task
    def start(self):
        global running
        with run_flag_lock:
            if not running:
                app2 = App2()  # create task thread
                app2.start()
                running = True

    # stop the task
    def stop(self):
        global running
        with run_flag_lock:
            if running:
                running = False

    # teminate GUI and stop task if it's running
    def quit(self):
        global running
        with run_flag_lock:
            if running:
                running = False
        self.root.destroy()


# class 2 with task in another thread
class App2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App2, self).__init__()  # base class initialization
        self.daemon = True  # allow main thread to terminate even if this one is running

    def run(self):
        global running
        # random work
        for i in range(10000):
            print(i)
            # Normally you shouldn't use sleep() in a tkinter app, but since this is in
            # a separate thread, it's OK to do so.
            sleep(.25)  # slow printing down a little
            # stop running if running flag is set to false
            with run_flag_lock:
                if not running:
                    break  # stop early

        with run_flag_lock:
            running = False  # task finished

# create (and start) main GUI app
app = App()
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear info and a possible solution. I will have to go deeper in threading.Is it the delay that is causing my loop to run slower?  Is that anything i can avoid or is that something i would want in my code ?

Comment: You didn't use the .pack() after changing the status_text, is that because you update the whole frame every 100 milisec? Is this kind of updating the frame something i better use in every program using a sort of 'interactive' tkinter frame? I just saw the .sleep statement you use in the loop to slow it down , didn't see that.

Comment: I intentionally added a call to `sleep()` inside the `for` loop that's in the `App2.run()` method **to** slow it down, which I see you figured-out. You only have to `pack()` a widget once. After that you can adjust its settings at any time by just using its `config()` method. How often (the speed-of-updating) is up to you. I chose 100 ms because it's less than the .25 sec delay I added to the 'for' loop in the thread (so it'll always keep-up with it).